# how to make a volume button follow mouse when clicked only

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs3

*I was making a simple sound player so i thought that it should also have volume control*

**so i made a volume button**

and **added** to it `Mouse_Down` event but it was only **listened to once**,
i am **confused** that how **should** i **detect the event again and again**,
if i get that i will write the code something like this in the event
//the numbers in code will not be same if i right it in the actual script

```
if !(button.x<400&&button.x>300)
{
button.x=MouseX
button.y=232
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code you're using for adding the event listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MOUSE_MOVE and check also buttonDown property in MouseEvent

ex:

```
stage.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moveHandler );
function moveHandler(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    if(e.buttonDown)
    {
    //do something
    }
}
```